# Can I efficiently create a pandas data frame from semi-structured binary data?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, binary

I need to convert large binary files to n x 3 arrays. The data is a series of image frames defined by (x, y, time) coordinates. Each frame uses two 32-bit integers to define the n x 3 dimensions, and n triplets of 16-bit integers to define the (x, y, time) values. The result is a binary structure that looks like:

`int32, int32, uint16, uint16, uint16, ..., int32, int32, uint16, uint16, uint16`, and so on.

My first attempt involved converting the binary data to a 1D array and then adding the sections I wanted to a data frame. The current data is already sorted in such a way that frame separation can be reconstructed without the two `int32` values, so they can be dropped if necessary. If this weren't the case, the same effect could be achieved by sorting each frame individually before adding it to the final data frame.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def frame_extract(index):
    n = data[index]
    subarray=data[index+4:index+(3*n+4)]
    subarray=np.reshape(subarray, (len(subarray)/3,3))
    frame = pd.DataFrame(data=subarray, columns=['x','y','t'])
    return frame

def indexer(index):
    n = data[index]
    new_index = index+(3*n+4)
    return new_index

data = np.fromfile('file.bin', dtype='<u2')
framedata = pd.DataFrame()

index = 0
while index <= len(data)-1:
    framedata = framedata.append(frame_extract(index), ignore_index=True)
    index = indexer(index)
print(framedata)
```

The above works, but the while loop is very slow, especially when compared to the following structured method, which would work fine (and orders of magnitude faster) if the `int32` values were not in the way:

```
dt = np.dtype([('x', '<u2'), ('y', '<u2'), ('time', '<u2')])
data = np.fromfile("file.bin", dtype=dt)
df = pd.DataFrame(data.tolist(), columns=data.dtype.names)
```

Is there a more efficient way of approaching this? If so, would it be easier to do while unpacking the binary data, or after it has been converted to integers?

I'm currently considering using a generator to read the binary file as a series of chunks (i.e. to use the two 32-bit integers to decide how large the 16-bit integer chunk I need is), but I'm not yet familiar enough with these to know if that's the right approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `count` parameter simplified this by allowing `np.fromfile` to take advantage of the structure defined by the `int32` values. The following `for` loop creates each image frame individually:

```
f = open('file.bin', 'rb')
for i in np.arange(1,15001,1): 
    m, n = np.fromfile(f, dtype='<i', count=2)
    frame = np.reshape(np.fromfile(f, dtype='<u2', count=m*n), (m, n))
```

Each frame can be added to a list and converted to a data frame using:

```
f = open('file.bin', 'rb')
xyt_data = list()
for i in np.arange(1,15001,1):
    m, n = np.fromfile(f, dtype='<i', count=2)
    frame = np.reshape(np.fromfile(f, dtype='<u2', count=m*n), (m, n))
    xyt_data.append(frame)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.vstack(xyt_data), columns=['x','y','t'])
```

The result is about three orders of magnitude faster than the version described in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you append to the data frame, you are copying the whole thing to a new location in memory. You will want to initialise the data frame with a numpy array with the full final size, and then index into that with iloc(), etc. when you populate it with the imaging data.

Also, is there a specific reason you are using pandas data frames to store imaging data? They are not really meant for that...

Comment: Thanks, populating an initialized data frame was significantly faster and provided a workable solution. Iterating through the file turned out to be more efficient, however, so I edited the original post to reflect that. I used pandas to be in line with other programs my group uses; there was no special reason.